# Replace element of a 3X4 matrix by value from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 3x4 matrix and I want to replace the element in the matrix if it meets certain condition (say >0.5 here) with the value that in the same axis=1. Should I slice the matrix or is there a better way?

```
matrix = np.array([[0.1, 0.9, 0.9, 0],
                    [0.8, 0.2, 0, 0.1],
                    [0.2, 0.1, 0, 0]])
array = np.array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Expected Results:

```
([[0.1, b, c, 0],
[a, 0.2, 0, 0.1],
[0.2, 0.1, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: and I assume you don't want to do a double loop through?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this without going through each element and comparing them

Comment: The other array is made of strings?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh No, the matrix is large.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes it's made of strings. The optimal is to replace the rest of the elements to np.nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
rows, columns = np.where(matrix > 0.5)
matrix = matrix.astype(object)  # need it to set the string values
matrix[rows, columns] = array[columns]
print(matrix)
```

**Output**

```
[[0.1 'b' 'c' 0.0]
 ['a' 0.2 0.0 0.1]
 [0.2 0.1 0.0 0.0]]
```